# Express.js can't handle GET route

Tags: node.js, express

I can't handle GET request which is in 'text/html' type.

**app.js**

```
...
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.json()); 
//Tried these also
//app.use(bodyParser.json())
//app.use(bodyParser.text())
//app.use(bodyParser.text({type:'text/*'}))

require('./routes')(app);
...
```

**routes.js**

```
const Api= require('./api');
module.exports = (app) => {
   app.get('/wa', Api.handleRequest);
}
```

Request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8081/wa?action_name=dosomething&idsite=1&tp=1&aq=42215
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:[::1]:8081
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept:image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9,tr;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:....
Host:localhost:8081
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8080/dashboard
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
```

As you can see I got 404. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the content of `const Api= require('./api');` look like?  Are you exporting a route object there?  If so you want to utilize the following instead: `app.use('/wa', Api.handleRequest);`

Comment: I tried your code with Postman and it worked fine for me. `handleRequest()` was `res.status(200).send('ok');`. I also started express in the bottom of app.js. I don't see why you have a status code in the request though. Is it actually the response?

Comment: @dvsoukup it exports a function which is like handleRequest(req,res){...} it doesn't get inside of it.

Comment: @MikaS request type is 'text/html' and there is no content-type. maybe it is because of that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I changed the route and the request url to '/wa.js' it works. In response I send a blank gif. Strange though..

**Request**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8081/wa.js?action_name=dosomething&idsite=1&tp=1&aq=42215
```

**routes.js**

```
 ...
 app.get('/wa.js', Api.handleRequest);
 ...
```